# Compiling a C++ program with v8 library with cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, v8

I've been working on a project using the v8 C++ library, I used to compile it with a Makefile, but to the extent that I'm using CLion and I wanted to debug, I had to use a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The problem I have is that the Makefile is working, but not the cmake...

Here's the Makefile:

```
NAME    = project

SRC = src/main.cpp

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

CXXFLAGS = -Iv8/include -std=c++11

LIBV8 = -Lv8/out/native/obj.target/third_party/icu/. -Lv8/out/native/obj.target/src/. -Wl,--start-group -lv8_base -lv8_libbase -lv8_external_snapshot -lv8_libplatform -lv8_libsampler -licuuc -licui18n -Wl,--end-group

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    g++  -pthread -lSDL2 $^ -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBV8) -lrt -ldl
```

And here's the CMake version I made:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Project CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/include)
include_directories(/usr/include/SDL2)

set(SDL2_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a)

find_package(Threads)

set(LIBV8
        v8_base
        v8_libbase
        v8_external_snapshot
        v8_libplatform
        v8_libsampler
        icuuc
        icui18n
        rt
        dl
        )
link_directories(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/out/native/obj.target/src/
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/out/native/obj.target/third_party/icu/
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
        )

add_executable(project ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(project ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${LIBV8})
```

I think I have correctly linked all the necessary libraries, but when I compile with the CMake version, I have tons of those errors (they are too many for my terminal, so I'll just put a snippet, "référence indéfinie vers" means "undefined reference to"):

```
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormatC2EPKdPKaPKNS_13UnicodeStringEi+0x43): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::MessagePattern(UErrorCode&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::ChoiceFormat(icu_59::ChoiceFormat const&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormatC2ERKS0_+0x3f): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::MessagePattern(icu_59::MessagePattern const&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::ChoiceFormat(icu_59::UnicodeString const&, UParseError&, UErrorCode&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormatC2ERKNS_13UnicodeStringER11UParseErrorR10UErrorCode+0x35): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::MessagePattern(UErrorCode&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::operator==(icu_59::Format const&) const »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZNK6icu_5912ChoiceFormateqERKNS_6FormatE+0x3a): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::operator==(icu_59::MessagePattern const&) const »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::operator=(icu_59::ChoiceFormat const&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormataSERKS0_+0x39): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::operator=(icu_59::MessagePattern const&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::~ChoiceFormat() »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormatD2Ev+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::~MessagePattern() »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::~ChoiceFormat() »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormatD0Ev+0x13): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::~MessagePattern() »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::applyPattern(icu_59::UnicodeString const&, UErrorCode&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormat12applyPatternERKNS_13UnicodeStringER10UErrorCode+0x17): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::parseChoiceStyle(icu_59::UnicodeString const&, UParseError*, UErrorCode&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::applyPattern(icu_59::UnicodeString const&, UParseError&, UErrorCode&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormat12applyPatternERKNS_13UnicodeStringER11UParseErrorR10UErrorCode+0x12): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::parseChoiceStyle(icu_59::UnicodeString const&, UParseError*, UErrorCode&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::format(double, icu_59::UnicodeString&, icu_59::FieldPosition&) const »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZNK6icu_5912ChoiceFormat6formatEdRNS_13UnicodeStringERNS_13FieldPositionE+0x8e): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::getNumericValue(icu_59::MessagePattern::Part const&) const »
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZNK6icu_5912ChoiceFormat6formatEdRNS_13UnicodeStringERNS_13FieldPositionE+0x144): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessageImpl::appendSubMessageWithoutSkipSyntax(icu_59::MessagePattern const&, int, icu_59::UnicodeString&) »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::findSubMessage(icu_59::MessagePattern const&, int, double) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormat14findSubMessageERKNS_14MessagePatternEid+0x6e): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::getNumericValue(icu_59::MessagePattern::Part const&) const »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::parseArgument(icu_59::MessagePattern const&, int, icu_59::UnicodeString const&, icu_59::ParsePosition&) »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZN6icu_5912ChoiceFormat13parseArgumentERKNS_14MessagePatternEiRKNS_13UnicodeStringERNS_13ParsePositionE+0x5d): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::getNumericValue(icu_59::MessagePattern::Part const&) const »
/home/xobtah/v8_Build/v8/out/native/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.o: dans la fonction « icu_59::ChoiceFormat::clone() const »:
../third_party/icu/source/i18n/choicfmt.cpp:(.text._ZNK6icu_5912ChoiceFormat5cloneEv+0x4d): référence indéfinie vers « icu_59::MessagePattern::MessagePattern(icu_59::MessagePattern const&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'project' failed
make[2]: *** [project] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thank you very much for your attention, I appreciate that!

EDIT: `make VERBOSE=1` makes that for linking:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable project
/opt/cmake-3.7.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/project.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11   CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o project  -L/home/xobtah/Project/v8/out/native/obj.target/src  -L/home/xobtah/Project/v8/out/native/obj.target/third_party/icu  -L/home/xobtah/Project/v8/build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/home/xobtah/Project/v8/out/native/obj.target/src:/home/xobtah/Project/v8/out/native/obj.target/third_party/icu:/home/xobtah/Project/v8/build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -rdynamic -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lv8_base -lv8_libbase -lv8_external_snapshot -lv8_libplatform -lv8_libsampler -licuuc -licui18n -lrt -ldl
```

Comment: You can try `make VERBOSE=1` to see exact linker command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my post to add the linker line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` around the actual v8 libraries in your `target_link_libraries()`.

If your objective is to replicate the Makefile, the libraries in your Makefile "LIBV8" are not the same as the libraries in your CMake "LIBV8".

Comment: Thank you very much, adding -Wl,--start-group and -Wl,--end-group before and after the set of libraries did the trick
I also had a problem with SDL2 library, but I solved it with this: https://brendanwhitfield.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/using-cmake-with-sdl2/