# C++ V8 Embedding project structure

Tags: c++, google-chrome, embed, v8

I'm trying to get chrome V8 embedded in my C++ project, and I can only get what I could call, my project being embedded in V8. My only concern with this is that my program is cross-platform and I would like build commands to be the same. I started development it on Windows, but I'm using a mac now to get V8 running.

I can get V8 built and their samples running using this setup:

- Get this: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up
- get source: https://v8.dev/docs/source-code
- build: https://v8.dev/docs/build

My current solution has a few commands `install`, `build`, `run`. The build command is more complicated as it attempts to automatically edit the `BUILD.gn` file in V8 to insert your project instead of V8. It will add all files in your source directory to the sources.

This approach feels very wrong for a few reasons. The first being that there is almost definitely a better way to configure my project than editing a build script with a python script. Secondly, I would like V8 to be embedded in my project, not the other way around. I only have SDL2 as a dependency but I have cross platform CMake builds setup, which would be abandoned for however V8 builds the source files. I feel this way could get hard to manage if I add more dependencies.

I'm currently working with a small test project with one source file.

EDIT: I can't find anything on embedding V8 between running a sample and API usage

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to make an adapter for v8 and sdl build systems incapsulating their build process details and exposing desired build interface.

Comment: @VTT I'm not sure exactly how the V8 build system is supposed to be used. They have a custom build scripting language (gm or gn, I'm not sure) which I don't think is required to learn (all of it) to use this project. As far as I can tell, the main way is the way I'm using it but it seems very wrong and I can't find anything telling me otherwise

Comment: Yeah, they have that weird GN system now, but you don't need to switch your project to use that build system. Just make an adapter so you can deal with your own and third-party projects in the uniform manner.

Comment: @VTT Okay, my project is actually split into a dynamic library (which includes SDL) and a (small) executable that includes that dynamic library. I could build the runtime as I have been and add my library as a dependency in their build system which sounds like it might work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to have a step in your build system that builds the V8 library as a dependency (as well as any other dependencies you might have). For that, it should use the official V8 build instructions. If you have a split between steps to get sources/dependencies and compiling them, then getting depot_tools and calling `fetch_v8`/`gclient sync` belongs in there. Note that you probably want to pin a version (latest stable branch) rather than using tip-of-tree. So, in pseudocode, you'd have something like:

```
step get_dependencies:
  download/update depot_tools
  download/update V8 @ pinned_revision (using depot_tools)

step compile (depends on "get_dependencies"):
  cd v8; gn args out/...; ninja -C out/...;
  cd sdl; build sdl
  build your own code, linking against V8/sdl/other deps.
```

Many build systems already have convenient ways to do these things. I don't know CMake very well though, so I can't suggest anything specific there.

I agree that using scripts to automatically modify `BUILD.gn` feels wrong. It'll probably also turn out to be brittle and high-maintenance over time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859161/compiling-a-c-program-with-v8-library-with-cmake but I get missing symbols and my own method with globbing `v8/out/*.o` but I get duplicate errors. I can't find documentation on what to include or even if this is supported

Comment: The official documentation is at https://v8.dev/docs/embed. Putting those command lines into your cmake files should do the trick?

Comment: @jmrk I tried to use these instructions and the build failed. I also took the latest `stable` `linux` branch and the build failed, too.

Comment: @EugeneGr.Philippov: "the build failed" is not a problem description anyone can help you with, and the comments section under an existing question/answer is not a good place to debug a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got V8 building with CMake very easily using brew:

`brew install v8`

then add the following lines to CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE V8_LIB # just GLOB is probably fine
    "/usr/local/opt/v8/lib/*.dylib"
)
include_directories(
    YOUR_INCLUDES
    /usr/local/opt/v8
    /usr/local/opt/v8/include
)
target_link_libraries(YOUR_PROJECT LINK_PUBLIC YOUR_LIBS ${V8_LIB})
```

Worked on Mojave 10.14.1